# Accessing returned dict's key, while resolved to value as expected, triggers KeyError?

Tags: python, basehttprequesthandler

I have a function that generates and returns a `_GET` dictionary containing the query key/value pairs of an URI's query field. Assuming the URI is `http://127.0.0.1/path/to/query?foo=bar&bar=foo`, the function is used like this inside a derived `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler` with noted `KeyError`:

```
class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Type", "text/plain")
        self.end_headers()

        _GET = query_parse(urlparse.urlparse(self.path).query)

        # No KeyError here..
        print "foo: %s\r\nbar: %s" % (GET["foo"], _GET["bar"])

        # KeyError on _GET["foo"]..
        self.wfile.write("foo: %s\r\nbar: %s\r\n" % (_GET["foo"], _GET["bar"]))

        # Still KeyError on _GET["foo"] even if commenting above line
        # and uncommenting below one!
        #self.wfile.write("bar: %s\r\nfoo: %s\r\n" % (_GET["bar"], _GET["foo"]))
```

Traceback:

```
localhost - - [19/Oct/2011 18:21:18] "GET /path/to/query?foo=bar&bar=foo HTTP/1.1" 200 -
localhost - - [19/Oct/2011 18:21:18] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 284, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 310, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 323, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\SocketServer.py", line 639, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 337, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "E:\Program\Python27\lib\BaseHTTPServer.py", line 325, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "http-test.py", line 40, in do_GET
    print "foo: %s" % _GET["foo"]
KeyError: 'foo'
```

Comment: In your line that succeeds, you are looking inside `GET`.  In the failing line, you are looking inside `_GET`.  Is this a typo in your post, or in your code?

Comment: Good eye! although I edited some things and happened to screw up here in stackoverflow: the original code is proper (and still triggering KeyError)

Comment: What if you inverse the two lines (the one that is fine and the one that causes the error) ?

Comment: I had them reversed initially actually, with same outcome (KeyError on write() like before). Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Could you post more of your code (such as `query_parse`), and repost `HTTPHandler` without editing?

Comment: I'm now using urlparse.parse_qsl as suggested by mouad, but still getting KeyError ! FYI I also reverting to have the "print" line before the "write()" line again and now "print" is the cause !

Comment: how about this - for our benefit, could you post the results of `print _GET`?

Comment: Using parse_qsl() as suggested by others it gives: _GET: {'foo': 'bar', 'bar': 'foo'}

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your `query_parse` function do but there is already a function that do that which is [`urlparse.parse_qs`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qs):

```
>>> query = urlparse.urlparse('http://127.0.0.1/path/to/query?foo=bar&bar=foo').query
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(query)
{'bar': ['foo'], 'foo': ['bar']}
```

Or if you don't like the value of the dictionary to be lists you can do:

```
>>> dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(query))
{'bar': 'foo', 'foo': 'bar'}
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and while I'll obviously use these standard APIs from now on, and while I'm doing it right now, I still suffer from KeyError!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query_parse(), use Python's own query parser:

```
>>> s = 'http://127.0.0.1/path/to/query?foo=bar&bar=foo'
>>> t = urlparse.urlparse(s)
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(t.query)
{'foo': ['bar'], 'bar': ['foo']}
```

This would have been easy to see with pdb or by inserting print statements to aid debugging.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have already one this as suggested by mouad, but I still get KeyError (the value is returned as expected but KeyError nevertheless!! )